# How can I convert this WordPress JSON entry into PHP array?

Tags: json, wordpress, interface

I am working on an interface to load data from a WordPress application into my own database. One table record comes with this:

```
a:6:{i:0;s:2:"39";i:1;s:2:"88";i:2;s:2:"89";i:3;s:2:"53";i:4;s:2:"54";i:5;s:2:"91";}
```

I know what this is representing and I think its a kind of JSON format, but I don't know how to convert this string into a readable PHP array.

I´ve tried to `explode()` something like `explode(';')`, but the result doesn't make any sense.

Have anyone seen this and can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a JSON string. It's a [serialized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array.

To make the serialized string into a regular array again, use [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

```
$serialized_array = 'a:6:{i:0;s:2:"39";i:1;s:2:"88";i:2;s:2:"89";i:3;s:2:"53";i:4;s:2:"54";i:5;s:2:"91";}';
$unserialized_array = unserialize($serialized_array);

var_dump( $unserialized_array );
```